# optimize tables for search using LIKE clause in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I am building a search feature for the messages part of my site, and have a messages database with a little over 9,000,000 rows, and and index on the `sender`, `subject`, and `message` fields. I was hoping to use the LIKE mysql clause in my query, such as (ex)

SELECT `sender`, `subject`, `message` FROM `Messages` WHERE `message` LIKE '%EXAMPLE_QUERY%';

to retrieve results. unfortunately, MySQL doesn't use indexes when a leading wildcard is present , and this is necessary for the search query could appear anywhere in the message (this is how the wildcards work, no?). Queries are **very very slow** and I cannot use a full text index either, because of the annoying 50% rule (I just can't afford to rule that much out). Is there anyway (or even, any alternative to this) to optimize a query using like and two wildcards? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You got 9 million rows and you can't filter by anything else except the message? No senddate nor sender?

Comment: Have a look at [SphinxSE](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse-using). I love it for this sort of thing.

Comment: @RobinCastlin i could, this is just an example. but search by message content is a critical feature in any messages app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use full-text indexes (you said you can't), design a full-text search by yourself or offload the search from MySQL and use Sphinx/Lucene. For Lucene you can use Zend_Search_Lucene implementation from Zend Framework or use Solr.

Normal indexes in MySQL are B+Trees, and they can't be used if the starting of the string is not known (and this is the case when you have wildcard in the beginning)

Another option is to implement search on your own, using reference table. Split text in words and create table that contains word, record_id. Then in the search you split the query in words and search for each of the words in the reference table. In this way you are not limitting yourself to the beginning of the whole text, but only to the beginning of the given word (and you'll match the rest of the words anyway)

Comment: great! all i needed to know. two questions, though.
1. is there any known way to force mysql to ignore the 50% rule when using full text searches?
2. would the lucene library make the searches efficient?

Comment: @roozbubu as far as I know, full-text queries that contain IN BOOLEAN MODE does not use the 50% rule - [read documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Answer (score 0):

`'%EXAMPLE_QUERY%';` is a very very bad idea .. am going to give you some

A. Avoid wildcards at the start of LIKE queries use `'EXAMPLE_QUERY%';` instead

B. Create Keywords where you can easily use `MATCH`

Comment: thanks for the tips! but 2 problems

a.if a avoid the beginning wildcard, won't it only search for something that BEGINS with that query, so if it shows up in the middle it is invalid?

b.the 50% rule prevents me from using match/against clauses

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with using MySQL, you should use FULL TEXT indexes. Full text indexes index words in a text block. You can then search on word stems and return the results in order of relevance. So you can find the word "example" within a block of text, but you still can't search efficiently on "xampl" to find "example".

MySQL's full text search is not great, but it is functional.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from emp where ename like '%e';
```

gives emp_name that ends with letter e.

```
select * from emp where ename like 'A%';
```

gives emp_name that begins with letter a.

```
select * from emp where ename like '_a%';
```

gives emp_name in which second letter is a.